# The reason for using the subjunctive in "elle n’en avait encore presque pas un que je ne lui eusse vu inventer"

Tags: subjonctif

The question is on the emboldened word in this passage from chapter 5 of La porte étroite by André Gide.  The letter (italicized) is from Alissa.

> La lettre suivante ne parlait que de la naissance de sa nièce, dont elle devait être marraine, de la joie de Juliette, de celle de mon oncle… mais de ses sentiments à elle, il n’était plus question.
>        
>   Puis ce furent des lettres datées de Fongueusemare de nouveau, où Juliette vint la rejoindre en juillet…
>        
>   *Édouard et Juliette nous ont quittés ce matin. C’est ma petite filleule surtout que je regrette ; quand je la reverrai, dans six mois, je ne reconnaîtrai plus tous ses gestes ; elle n’en avait encore presque pas un que je ne lui **eusse** vu inventer. Les formations sont toujours si mystérieuses et surprenantes ! c’est par défaut d’attention que nous ne nous étonnons pas plus souvent. Que d’heures j’ai passées, penchée sur ce petit berceau plein d’espérance. Par quel égoïsme, quelle suffisance, quelle inappétence du mieux, le développement s’arrête-t-il si vite, et toute créature se fixe-t-elle encore si distante de Dieu ? Oh ! si pourtant nous pouvions, nous voulions nous rapprocher de Lui davantage… quelle émulation ce serait !*

**QUESTION**

1. If the child had many gestures the invention of which Alissa had not seen, which of the following would be the proper way to express that?

> (A) elle en avait beaucoup que je ne lui **avait** vu inventer
>   (B) elle en avait beaucoup que je ne lui **eus** vu inventer
>   (C) elle en avait beaucoup que je ne lui **eusse** vu inventer

2. Why is Gide's original (duplicated below) in the subjunctive?

> (G) elle n’en avait encore presque pas un que je ne lui **eusse** vu inventer

3. If Gide had used the indicative, would that have been ungrammatical?  I.e., is the following ungrammatical?

> (G') elle n’en avait encore presque pas un que je ne lui **avait (eus)** vu inventer

**BACKGROUND**

If I had to hazard a guess, I would start by noting that Alissa had in fact seen almost all the gestures at their invention.  Therefore, the idea of the *que* clause--namely, that Alissa had not seen their invention--is contrary to fact.  The subjunctive *eusse* marks this counterfactuality.

If this guess is correct, then the answer to 1 would have to be (A) or (B) because there is no counterfactuality there. In this case, I have no good sense of why (A) or (B), as the case may be, would be preferable except that I have not seen many verbs in passé antérieur.

Comment: Another instance from the same book: *Qu’aurions-nous à nous dire que nous ne nous **soyons** déjà écrit ?* Only instead of the explicit negative  (referred to in Teleporting Goat's answer), we have a question (an implicit negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon said, *subjonctif imparfait* is almost never used now, so in order for my own sentences to sound familiar I'll use *subjonctif présent*.

Basically, there is a construction in French that goes :

> Il n'y a rien que [subjonctif]

Here are some examples :

> Il n'y a rien que **je puisse** faire.
>
> N'y a-t-il personne ici qui **sache** comment faire ?
>
> Il n'y a pas grand chose qui **soit** capable de le faire réagir.

1. It is possible only with **negative** sentences (*rien*, *personne*, *presque pas*,...) so you can't use that tense with "*Il y en avait beaucoup*". I think the correct one is "*Il y en avait beaucoup que je ne lui avais (pas) vu inventer*". I'm not 100% sure though, it's not a tense I use a lot.
2. See above.
3. According to [this thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-il-ny-a-rien-que-mode.2027995/?hl=fr), it isn't grammatical to use indicative here. In colloquial langage you might hear it but it's a mistake.

Ex: "Nothing can stop me"

> Il n'y a rien qui puisse m'arrêter

Correct, but very formal

> *Il n'y a rien qui peut m'arrêter*

Not correct but can be heard. Colloquial.

> Rien ne peut m'arrêter

Correct, less formal than the first one, but not as colloquial as the second.

---

I found other used of this construction in popular phrases :

> Il y a pas de "mais" qui tienne !

When a parent is scolding their child and they respond, for example. "Mais" can be replaced with anything, the phrase means it's not receivable, you're not in place to say "but..." or ask for the thing.

> Il n'y a que *Maille* qui m'aille

Slogan of the mustard brand "Maille". "Only *Maille* can satisfy me".

Comment: Thank you.  But one question. Why should (A) be without *ne*? It would seem that both (affirmative & negative) should be possible. I.e. the child could have many *que je lui avait vu inventer* (*that I had seen her invent*) or *que je ne lui avait vu inventer* (*that I had not seen her invent*). Just depends on the facts, no?

Comment: @Catomic Ooh yeah sure, I thought you forgot to remove it, it would have been clearer with "*ne ...* ***pas***", but it *is* correct to omit "*pas*" especially in book language. My bad !

Comment: Do you mean *subjonctif* is only possible with negative sentences? Because I'm pretty sure that it's wrong, and *je veux que tu le saches*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps No, only with the construction "*Il n'y a [negative] qui [* subjonctif *]*" (and in some others). I'm pretty sure you can't say "*Il y a quelque chose qui **puisse** l'arrêter*". There are other constructions that use *subjonctif* when they are negative : "*Je crois qu'on peux...*" / "*Je ne crois pas qu'on puisse...*" but of course you can use *subjonctif* in positive sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In a sentence with a *main clause* and a *subordinate clause* that takes place **before** the main clause, you must use the *subjonctif passé*:

> Il **faut** que tu **aies fini** tes devoirs avant te sortir.

If the main clause is already in a past tense, so you must use the *subjonctif plus-que-parfait*:

> Il **fallait** que tu **eusses fini** tes devoirs avant de sortir.

Nowadays the *subjonctif passé* is often used instead:

> Il **fallait** que tu **aies fini** tes devoirs avant de sortir.

Comment: Thank you, but is *falloir* perhaps driving the requirement in your examples? Consider the French for: "We found the dog again that we had seen the day before."  Would *voir* be in the subjunctive?

Comment: It's important to know that *subjonctif imparfait* is never used, but that doesn't really answer any of OP's questions. I think the main question is "why is there subjunctive here ?"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hum you are right, I don't know why I've understood the question that way.